# Gitlab pages для своего Gitlab

Tags: github, gitlab

Gitlab pages позволяет публиковать index.html туда.

Есть свой развернутый GitLab последней версии. что мне нужно делать, чтобы я смог использовать свой основной DNS и опубликовал также сайт?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно установить и запустить [GitLab Pages daemon](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-pages) — это их собственный вебсервер. Он может быть установлен как на одном хосте с гитлабом, так и на отдельном.

Поставляется он в пакете Omnibus или отдельно.

Подробные инструкции есть в [GitLab Pages configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/pages/index.html).

Также можно установить и сконфигурировать с помощью роли Ansible [debops.ansible-gitlab](https://github.com/debops/ansible-gitlab).